# Why Head of Integrate of a expression is not Integrate?

Tags: functions

I was checking TreeForm of some expressions, What i'm thinking is TreeForm will give picture showing the main function acting in expression at top and sub main functions and so on and at the end only elements will be shown in tree diagram. What I found interesting is When applied to Integrate function.

[image]

Integrate is a function like Sin and Cos then why is shown in tree diagram

[image]

Comment: Because `Integrate[Sin[x], x]` evaluates to `-Cos[x]`. Try `Integrate[Sin[x], x] // Hold // TreeForm`.

Comment: @xzczd,Hi, With Hold function it is showing .Thanks  a lot.